# angular-js reuseable directives with two way binding

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to create a few different directives that will work as search / filter tools for different parts of my application.

For this purpose i have created the following directive code:

```
    app.directive("lbFilterDivision", ['divisionService', function (divisionService) {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        templateUrl: 'tpl/directives/lb-filters/lbFilterDivision.html',
        scope: {
            model: '='
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {
            scope.divisions = [];
            divisionService.getList().then(function (result) {
                scope.divisions = result;
            })
        }
    };
}]);
```

The template attached to this is:

```
<select class="form-control"
    ng-model="model"
    ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in divisions"
    fix-select-null="">
<option value="" translate="FORMS.DIVISION_PLACEHOLDER"></option>
```

Okay first of all let me explain the main idea.

The idea is that you have a `search` variable that will be passed to the directive. Then the two way binding should notify up through the system.

So say for instance i have the following HTML:

```
<lb-filter-division model="search.division.id"></lb-filter-division>
<li ng-repeat="user in users | filter:search"> </li>
```

As you can see i set the `model` = to `search.division.id` which means every time i change selected variable it should update the `search.division.id` variable and filter the list.

Sadly this is not the case.

Can anyone see what ive done wrong?

**Edit** - I found the answer. Apprently there was a syntax error in my code. Im so sorry! i will leave this code here if someone gets the same idea as my self.

Here is a fiddle:

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/20013/)

Comment: When it comes to 2-way binding, shouldn't it be like this: `model="{{ search.division.id }}"`?

Comment: shouldn't the filter be used like `<li ng-repeat="user in users | filter:search.division.id"> </li>` ?

Comment: @dave when '=' is used in the directive it is defined as a binding

Comment: @yarons no because if i limit my self to that i would be unable to put extra search filters on

Comment: @MarcRasmussen but this is how `filter` works. you might want to create a custom filter instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem.

If you wish to copy or are looking to solve the same issue i can refer to this fiddle i made:

```
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'Superhero';

    $scope.users = [
        {id: 1, name: "div1", division:{id: 1, name: 'hello'}},
        {id: 2, name: "div2", division:{id: 2, name: 'hello2'}},
        {id: 3, name: "div3", division:{id: 3, name: 'hello3'}}

    ]
}

myApp.directive("lbFilterDivision", function () {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        scope: {
            model: '='
        },
      template: '<select ng-model="model" ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in divisions"></select>',
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {
            scope.divisions = [{id: 1, name:'hello'},{id: 2, name:'hello2'},{id: 3, name:'hello2'}];
        }
    };
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/20013/)

Good luck!